# Docusign: Embedded Signing with Access Code Issue - Unable to Sign Using Recipient View URL

Tags: docusignapi

I'am creating a Python App which uses the Docusign API. I create an envelope and requiere an Access Code. But i want to use embedded signing, so i make another API call to get the Recipient view. But with the URL that is returned I'am not able to sign and no Access code is asked. If i sign via the recived email i get asked for Access code and everything works just fine

```
#Construct the Base URL
base_uri = f"{base_url}/accounts/{account_id}"

#Create the Envelope Definition
envelope_definition = {
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign the Document",  # Add a subject line
    "documents": [{"documentBase64": "", "name": "Document.pdf", "fileExtension": "pdf", "documentId": "1"}],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": recipient_email,
                "name": recipient_name,
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{"anchorString": "/sn1/", "anchorUnits": "pixels", "anchorXOffset": "10", "anchorYOffset": "10"}]
                },
                "templateAccessCodeRequired": None,
                "deliveryMethod": "email",
                "smsAuthentication": None,
        "idCheckConfigurationName": None,
                "requireIdLookup": False,
                "accessCode": "123456",

            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent",
}

with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
    content_bytes = file.read()
    content_base64 = base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    envelope_definition["documents"][0]["documentBase64"] = content_base64

#Send the Envelope
url = f"{base_uri}/envelopes"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=envelope_definition)

# Check for errors in the response
if response.status_code != 201:
    print(f"Error creating envelope. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
    exit()

envelope_id = response.json()["envelopeId"]
print(response.json()["uri"])

#Get the Signing URL
url = f"{base_uri}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/views/recipient"
recipient_view_request = {
    "returnUrl": "https://www.example.com/success",
    "authenticationMethod": "none",
    "email": recipient_email,
    "userName": recipient_name,
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=recipient_view_request)
print(response.json())
signing_url = response.json()["url"]


#Return the Signing URL
print(f"Signing URL: {signing_url}")
```

This is my code. I had a look at the DocuSign website but i found nothing matching for authenticationMethod

I was able to sign documents via the url of the recipient view fine without the Access code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing **clientUserId** in two places in your code. Here is updated code:

```
#Construct the Base URL
base_uri = f"{base_url}/accounts/{account_id}"

#Create the Envelope Definition
envelope_definition = {
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign the Document",  # Add a subject line
    "documents": [{"documentBase64": "", "name": "Document.pdf", "fileExtension": "pdf", "documentId": "1"}],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": recipient_email,
                "name": recipient_name,
                "recipientId": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [{"anchorString": "/sn1/", "anchorUnits": "pixels", "anchorXOffset": "10", "anchorYOffset": "10"}]
                },
                "templateAccessCodeRequired": None,
                "deliveryMethod": "email",
                "smsAuthentication": None,
        "idCheckConfigurationName": None,
                "requireIdLookup": False,
                "accessCode": "123456",
                "clientUserId" : "1001",
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent",
}

with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
    content_bytes = file.read()
    content_base64 = base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    envelope_definition["documents"][0]["documentBase64"] = content_base64

#Send the Envelope
url = f"{base_uri}/envelopes"
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=envelope_definition)

# Check for errors in the response
if response.status_code != 201:
    print(f"Error creating envelope. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.text)
    exit()

envelope_id = response.json()["envelopeId"]
print(response.json()["uri"])

#Get the Signing URL
url = f"{base_uri}/envelopes/{envelope_id}/views/recipient"
recipient_view_request = {
    "returnUrl": "https://www.example.com/success",
    "authenticationMethod": "none",
    "email": recipient_email,
    "clientUserId" : "1001",
    "userName": recipient_name,
}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=recipient_view_request)
print(response.json())
signing_url = response.json()["url"]


#Return the Signing URL
print(f"Signing URL: {signing_url}")
```